# Android ShareActionProvider adds unwanted items to toolbar?

Tags: java, android

Why does my toolbar expand with the message icon when i've used it once in the ShareActionProvider?
I dont want this behaviour.

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Why does my toolbar expand with the message icon when i've used it once in the ShareActionProvider?

That is the `ShareActionProvider` providing a recent or popular share action to the user, for rapid access. Quoting [the documentation](https://developer.android.com/reference/kotlin/androidx/appcompat/widget/ShareActionProvider#share-target-rankings):

> The share action provider retains a ranking for each share target, based on how often the user chooses each one. The more often a user chooses a target, the higher its rank; the most-commonly used target appears in the app bar as the default target.

---

> I dont want this behaviour.

I suspect that you do not have a choice in the matter, if you are going to use `ShareActionProvider`. You can try calling [`setShareHistoryFilename()`](https://developer.android.com/reference/kotlin/androidx/appcompat/widget/ShareActionProvider?hl=en#setsharehistoryfilename) and provide `null` for the filename and see if that suppresses the behavior.

Comment: Oh well okay i didn't know that this is intentionally. Thanks :D